# Separar String separada por virgula VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba, split

Estou com um pequeno problema, estou fazendo a leitura da porta serial do computador e armazenando em uma string em VBA, o dado recebido seria um conjunto de 13 instâncias separados por virgula.

A solução seria bem simples, porem posso estar cometendo algum erro e nao estou fazendo da forma correta.

Dado a ser recebido: 0.00,,,,,,-30.00,,,,,,,/ entre as virgulas recebo vários sinais de sensores que nao sao uniformes, posso receber  de 2 a 6 caracteres por separação.

```
lngStatus = CommRead(intPortID, strData, 1)     ' armazeno buffer em srtData
    If lngStatus > 0 Then                       ' se status de CommRead Ok libera flag
  
  arrSplitStrings1() = Split(strData, ",")      ' faz split separando cada , em uma casa do vetor arrSplitStrings1
 
 
 Range("A2") = arrSplitStrings1(0)              ' armazena na celula a2 a possicao 0 do buffer
 

     

    ElseIf lngStatus < 0 Then
        ' Handle error.
    End If
```

O problema acontece que a função split esta separando somente a primeira posição, se eu  coletar o tamanho do vetor arrSplitStrings1 com o UBound  retorna 0.

Quando tento armazenar a posição 1 o Excel retorna "subscrito fora do intervalo".

Comment: nao deveria ser arrSplitStrings1 = Split(strData, ",")  sem as aspas do arrSpliStrings1. Já confirmaste o conteudo de strData quando recebes do serial ?

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver o problema...
A  instancia abaixo criava uma chamada dupla, sendo a primeira o buffer vindo da serial, e o segundo um buffer vazio.

```
CommRead(intPortID, strData, 1)
```

O problema acontecia quando a funcao "Split" tentava encontrar a "," no segundo buffer e nao a encontrava.

Contornei o problema avaliando o dado recebido, se maior que 15 caracteres ele liberava para fazer a funcao Split.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).